# The set of closed untyped $\lambda$-terms is not context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, lambda-calculus

The set of untyped $\lambda$-terms is obviously context-free.  But, according to Barendregt's paper [Discriminating coded lambda terms](https://repository.ubn.ru.nl/bitstream/handle/2066/17287/13356.pdf) (six lines before Theorem 1.5), the set of *closed* untyped $\lambda$-terms is not.  How can this be proved?

Comment: You can reduce the non-context-free language $\{a^nb^nc^n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ to it by mapping $a^nb^mc^r$ to $\lambda a^{(n)}\,(a^{(m)}a^{(r)})$ (here, $a^{(n)}=a^{\overbrace{\prime\dots\prime}^n}$ is the notation for the $n$th variable from Def. 1.1). Or just directly apply the pumping lemma to these terms.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, please make your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: This is not a research-level question. The arguments used in my comment are literally the first things to try when proving a language is not context-free, e.g., they are mentioned on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language), and their application to the language of $\lambda$-terms is obvious.